# Can't compile CUDA samples: ld: library not found for -lgomp clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: sdk, cuda, makefile, openmp

I'm trying to compile CUDA samples. If I cd to the sample, and then run `make` it gives me an error:

```
macair93278:samples r8t$ cd 0_Simple/UnifiedMemoryStreams/
macair93278:UnifiedMemoryStreams r8t$ ls
Makefile        Makefile-e      NsightEclipse.xml   UnifiedMemoryStreams.cu readme.txt
macair93278:UnifiedMemoryStreams r8t$ make
```

There's a couple warnings, then

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fopenmp'
ld: library not found for -lgomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING - OpenMP is unable to compile
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This CUDA Sample cannot be built if the OpenMP compiler is not set up correctly. 
This will be a dry-run of the Makefile.
For more information on how to set up your environment to build and run this sample, please refer the CUDA Samples documentation and release notes
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Apple's clang doesn't support OpenMP. You will not be able to compile and run that example

Comment: You're still issuing `make` instead of `make -k`.  Try issuing `make -k`.  It will not have any effect on this issue, but it should allow you to get other samples built.  You may be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159225/openmp-support-in-xcode-6-clang-3-5) also.

Comment: `make -k` worked! Thank you!